# 403 Forbidden when using specific parameter value in Rest URL

Tags: php, rest

I have an API that I created that's been working fine for me and my users for years.
You can use it to query something called "Card Sets" like so:

https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php?&cardsetocg=Metal%20Raiders

You can then use a URL encoded `;` to search multiple ones, like so:

https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php?&cardsetocg=Metal%20Raiders%3BMagic%20Ruler

We have a new set called `Selection 10` that is for some reason causing issues. We never had issues with the other 800+ ones.

Calling it alone works:

https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php?&cardsetocg=Selection%2010

Calling it with any other set causes `403 forbidden`:

https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php?&cardsetocg=Metal%20Raiders%3BSelection%2010

No other set causes this forbidden error. I have re-created the API in a separate file structure with a different `.htaccess` file and the issue persists.

**Server Information:**

- Apache CENTOS 7.9
- PHP 7.2

.htaccess contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

<FilesMatch "service-worker\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200, public, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<filesMatch "\.( jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2419200, public, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
deny from 70.24.57.210
deny from 204.14.239.137
```

EDIT:
Swapping the two parameter values around seems to make it work but isn't a solution or doesn't make me aware of the problem.

https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php?&cardsetocg=Selection%2010%3BMetal%20Raiders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was triggering the modsecurity server firewall.

It was being detected as a SQL injection attack due to this part in the URL:

```
;Select
```

In hindsight, it does make sense why that would be blocked and why leading with `Selection` seems to have been ok.